# uninstall paho-mqtt 1.2 python library

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I am using paho-mqtt 1.2 but time facing problem in connection to my mosquitto server hosted on AWS. I am getting RC value 1 which means "connection refused: unacceptable protocol version" I am able to connect to the server using paho-mqtt 1.1 version.
How can I remove or uninstall paho-mqtt 1.2 version from raspberry pi?

Comment: How did you install the library?

Comment: sudo python setup.py install